# Confusion matrix R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am struggling with this confusion matrix application:

```
lvs <- c("normal", "abnormal")
truth <- factor(rep(lvs, times = c(86, 258)),
levels = rev(lvs))
pred <- factor(
c(
rep(lvs, times = c(54, 32)),
rep(lvs, times = c(27, 231))),
levels = rev(lvs))
xtab <- table(pred, truth)
```

Basically, I am confused with line number 2, 6 and 7. Below you can see the result after running the code. But I am still confused what I have to put into the brackets. Of course, I know the values were just an example but in the tutorial it wasn't explained what these values mean.

https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/caret/html/confusionMatrix.html

```
truth
pred   abnormal  normal
abnormal   231       32
normal     27        54
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're more confused about how they create the dataset than the **confusionMatrix** itself. So i will try to explain step by step these lines.

Here, he just creates levels name to be used later in data generation.

```
lvs <- c("normal", "abnormal")
```

Now, he generates the vector to use as **true labels** of a test set, he replicates the levels name with `rep`, for each level he sets a specific number of times in the function argument. Afterwards, he transforms the vector as `factor` and assigns levels in reverse order of the levels name. The reverse order is to organize the order that functions as `table` will output the data.

```
truth <- factor(rep(lvs, times = c(86, 258)),levels = rev(lvs))
```

Here, it's the same process as above, by he joins two `rep` functions just to messy the data and to simulate **responses** from a predictor.

```
pred <- factor( c( rep(lvs, times = c(54, 32)), 
                   rep(lvs, times = c(27, 231))),
                   levels = rev(lvs) )
```

At last, you use the `table` function to create a confusion matrix, and with this table you can analyze many metrics as overall accuracy, sensibility, specificity. These metrics already come computed with `caret::confusionMatrix`.

```
xtab <- table(pred, truth)
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, truth)
```

The class assigned as **Positive class** is the first name of the levels vector in the factor instance.